# Why is facepalm emoji ‍♀️ followed by U+200D♀

Tags: utf-8, emoji

I am trying to send utf-8 symbols via serial device to browser and display them. I have found out when I print facepalm emoji ‍♀️ (on windows 10 <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>) it has `U+200D` and `♀` characters behind. Others emojis don't have that. I was using [View non-printable unicode characters](https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php) tool. Also I found, if you print it in notepad it will show you `♀`, when you print it in browser address bar `♀` is invisible but if you press backspace you delete it. And finally, if you print it in some html text input, you can delete whole emoji with single backspace. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emoji sequences have more than one code point to signify variations (below may or may not look different for each sequence depending on browser):

```
 PERSON FACEPALMING U+1F926
‍♂️ MAN FACEPALMING    U+1F926 U+200D U+2642 U+FE0F
‍♀️ WOMAN FACEPALMING  U+1F926 U+200D U+2640 U+FE0F
```

References:

- [Emoji List, v13.1](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-list.html) No. 260-262.
- [Full Emoji List, v13.1, No. 260-262](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#1f926) (With browser-specific images)
- [Unicode® Standard Annex #29, UNICODE TEXT SEGMENTATION](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/)

Some editors/browsers handle the sequences better than others and may not show differences in all variations or may not recognize the latest Unicode specfication and newer emojis.